# How to use DevOps Library variable groups in App Service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-appservice

As I heard, one can really use the Library values in one's app. But all documentation around this topic is incomplete or really wrong, I cannot make up how!
We already tried mapping the values into a JSON object in our .yaml pipeline and defining them in "Configuration" of the App Service. But nothing will make these variables/groups available in our app. They should be loaded by (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder) .AddEnvironmentVariables(); as I read. But so far none of them arrive in the app, but a hundert of others that I never defined anywhere do...

Can anyone tell me if this is really possible or some step missing or so? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: cn you see the variables loaded in the app settings blade from azure portal ? Also could you share your yaml ? at least the related pats/tasks please ?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to share any code. But in my pipeline directly I only have variables:

Comment: Without the YAML and/or tasks being leveraged I'm not sure how much help can be provided.  There are ways to load the variable values into the app service configuration settings but depends what task(s) you are using.

Comment: I need to use Terraform templates and there are no "tasks" defined. That was problem #1. But I an use a script in my pipeline at least. Can someone post ONE way of how to push a value from the pipeline to the Configuration (section) of an App Service? Thank you very much!